# How to access files in the Project Directory with Grails

Tags: grails, configuration, path

I needed some templates to render some code for users to paste. I put these into

```
/project-dir/grails-app/resources/templates/quickInstallCode.html
```

Then I tried accessing them using their relative path (`grails-app/resources/templates/quickInstallCode.html`), and it worked great.

When we then deployed the application to a Tomcat Server, using a .war file, the paths began pointing to a wrong location.

```
ERROR  call, Template file /var/lib/tomcat6/grails-app/resources/templates/quickInstallCode.html not found.
```

I assumed, that Grails, giving good defaults for everything would handle this mess for me, but it seems like it does not.

I also tried this call, and it seemed to work great, but when deployed, the BuildSettingsHolder did not contain build Settings, which resulted in a fatal error.

```
BuildSettingsHolder.settings.baseDir.toString()
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/BuildSettingsHolder.html
http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/BuildSettings.html

I am pretty frustrated that I cannot get this easy task to work, but the reason that this is so complicated seems to be that all Files are encapsuled in a WAR and not unpacked on the Server.

So the Questions are:

- Where in your Project would you put
  Files like this?
- How to get a
  reliable and stable way to access
  this files? I just need a stable path to a base directory, without having to hardcode something in the configuration ... This cannot be so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 solution to propose for this situation:

1. Save the template in the database, in a setting table. This way guarantees that nothing can go wrong.
2. You can consider using the resource folder like Sachin & Nirmal has proposed. About security, I think you can configure [SpringSecurity Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) to protect the specific resources, so that it can only be accessed by the site user.

Comment: Sadly it seems that there is no Answer that really satisfies my needs. Putting the Stuff in the Database seems like too much Overhead for me, and putting them in the Web Apps folder is to risky.
Seems like I, coming from a PHP World, still have to get used to the Grails Environment and it's pitfalls, like having the Server very abstracted.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [link](http://jermdemo.blogspot.com/2009/05/loading-files-in-grails-bootstrap.html) and try to use the getResource that spring provides. Its way more flexible and configurable.

```
def filePath = "resources/file.txt"
def appHolder=ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource("classpath:$filePath")
```

By the way Conf is on the root of the classpath, you can stick the files in src/java or src/groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my static resources in web-app folder and access them like this
ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.servletContext.getRealPath("quickInstallCode.html")
// quickInstallCode.html should be in web-app folder.

Comment: How do you handle files that should not be accessible to the public? I am not a Tomcat specialist, but I always thought that this folder was somehow accessible.